# How to use oracle TIMESTAMP with fractional seconds in NHibernate?

Tags: oracle, nhibernate, datetime

I have this mapping in my NHibernate.

LASTUPDATE is a TIMESTAMP row, which stores fractional seconds

However, when I have query like

```
q => q.Where(p => p.LastUpdate > _lastupdate);
```

where _lastupdate is a DateTime (with fractional seconds, of course) , NHibernate translate _lastupdate as  '2012-03-12 8:48:25', losing the fractional seconds.

How can I fix this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly map your property as `type="Timestamp"`

See [5.2.2. Basic value types](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-types-basictypes)

Comment: that will allow the property to be saved and loaded with fractional seconds, but when I have a where query like `(p => p.LastUpdate > _lastupdate)`, the translation loses the fractional seconds

Comment: That's odd. I just tried with SQL Server, and it passes the fractional seconds correctly. I don't have an Oracle db to test with; are you using the latest version? (3.2 or 3.3CR1)